# Create responsive element in right-side

Tags: html, css

I have problem with creating responsive div on this same height like image on left side. In this div I want to add text but when I'm doing it, paragraph stretches in height and div element too when I trying change resolution of window. [Check codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKvELR)

HTML:

```css
#left-side {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60em;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#left-side>div>img {
  margin-top: 15%;
  border: solid #A98646 2px;
  border-bottom: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 25%;
}

#right-side {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60em;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.description {
  margin-top: 15%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 72%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article id="left-side">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="img1.jpg">
    </div>
  </article>
  <article id="right-side">
    <div class="description">2</div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You want the green div to have the same height of the image? why then you set different heights to them ?

Comment: Yes, I want this same height. They have different heights because image is too big so I changed this for him. 
I want to create responsive div with description on right side with he similar width and height like image on left side.
Problem is in description inside this div, when I change resolution of window, paragraph scretching to bottom and div in this same moment changes height.

Answer (score 0):

What if you did something like this with `position:absolute;` on the `#right-side` element?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKzBqr)

```css
header{
    background-color: #282828;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35em;
}

header > h1{
    color: #A98646;
    font-family: 'Righteous';
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 6.75rem;
    
}

header .logo{
    width: 40px;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

header .logo:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

nav{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    margin-top: 0rem;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav li{
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
}

nav>ul>img{
    width: 100px;
}

header > p{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
}



#left-side{
    width: 50%;
    height: 60em;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.image {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#left-side>div>img{
    margin-top: 15%;
    border: solid #A98646 2px;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 75%;
}


#right-side{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}

.description{
    width: 50%;
    height: 75%;
    margin: 15% auto;
    background: green;

}


section { 
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article id="left-side">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="img1.jpg">
    </div>
  </article>
  <article id="right-side">
    <div class="description">2</div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes I know. I trying to find solution everywhere in code :D 
But still it is not this what I mean.
https://imgur.com/a/546EMeo
Here is what I want.this is how it looks when I change size of window.